# Two-dimensional hotelling equilibria

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Customers are heterogeneous with regard to their preference for quality $q$.
Specifically, a customer's utility from buying a product of quality $q$ at price $p$ is $V-p + \lambda q$, with $\lambda$ being uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. The mass of consumers is normalized to 1.
Two firms are competing with each other and they are differentiated in the quality level. Firm 1 and firms 2 have level $q_1$ and $q_2$, respectively; for convenience $q_1>q_2$ and sufficiently differentiated so that no mixed NE exists.
Customers buy the product from the firm that offers better utility but only if buying yields the customer non-negative utility.

In the case that $V$ is large, it is relatively easy to identify the equilibrium pricing strategies of the firms and I also found this paper "Competition in Multi-characteristics Spaces: Hotelling Was Almost Right".
Is there a paper that treats the more general case or is there a way to avoid discussing lots of cases?

Or alternatively, is there a model that captures these mechanics better?